# Received 0 instead of expected 7 bytes AMQPIOException - user is correct, only when queue is empty

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq

I use "php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle": "^1.14",

console command

```
 /app/console rabbitmq:consumer  parse_ppmconsumer -m 100
```

error is

```
Message: "Error reading data. Received 0 instead of expected 7 bytes" ["error" => PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPIOException { …},"command" => "rabbitmq:consumer parse_ppmconsumer -m 100","message" => "Error reading data. Received 0 instead of expected 7 bytes"] []
```

i found similar errors but they have error is permissions i check my:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl list_permissions -p /
[sudo] password for grek: 
Listing permissions in vhost "/" ...
guest   .*      .*      .*
root    .*      .*      .*
```

so its correct

situation is only when queue is empty , when i have some data i get

/app/console rabbitmq:consumer  parse_ppmconsumer -m 100
   00:00,1792631149292
00:00,048967838287354
00:00,037322998046875
00:00,062886953353882
00:00,009692907333374
00:00,02227783203125
00:00,028231859207153
00:00,033851146697998
00:00,0090358257293701
00:00,01706600189209
00:00,012717962265015
00:00,020620107650757
00:00,01526403427124
00:00,016094207763672
00:00,016033887863159
00:00,014401912689209

- this is every message proccessing time.

at the end i get :

```
00:00,078952074050903
00:00,12211585044861
00:00,3163890838623
00:00,5457661151886
18:53:27 ERROR     [console] Error thrown while running command "rabbitmq:consumer parse_ppmconsumer -m 100". Message: "Error reading data. Received 0 instead of expected 62 bytes" ["error" => PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPIOException { …},"command" => "rabbitmq:consumer parse_ppmconsumer -m 100","message" => "Error reading data. Received 0 instead of expected 62 bytes"] []


  [PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPIOException]                       
  Error reading data. Received 0 instead of expected 62 bytes
```

where is problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with socket connection to RabbitMQ message queue. AMQPSocketConnection does not support heartbeat as you can read [here](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/issues/272)

If you want to use sockets with preventing this error, disable "heartbeat" parameter in configuration file.

Try this configuration for rabbit_mq bundle:

```
old_sound_rabbit_mq:
    connections:
        default:
            host:     '%env(resolve:RABBITMQ_HOST)%'
            port:     '%env(resolve:RABBITMQ_PORT)%'
            user:     '%env(resolve:RABBITMQ_USER)%'
            password: '%env(resolve:RABBITMQ_PASSWORD)%'
            vhost:    '/'
            lazy:     false
            connection_timeout: 60
            read_write_timeout: 60
            # requires php-amqplib v2.4.1+ and PHP5.4+
            # keepalive: true
            # requires php-amqplib v2.4.1+
            # heartbeat: 30 - disable heartbeat support
            #requires php_sockets.dll
            use_socket: true # default false
```

Make sure you have installed mbstring, bcmath and sockets php extensions(this is important step)